# K-terminal graph connectivity check (using Networkx)

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a large undirected graph with `m` specific source and `n` specific terminal nodes, and I want to check whether there is a connection between all sources to all terminals or not. The answer will be a binary scalar, i.e. 1 if all sources are connected to all terminals, and 0 if there exists a source and a terminal which are not connected.

For one-source one-terminal connectivity, I can use Networkx to check the connection (which is based on the DFS algorithm):

```
has_path(G, source, target)
```

The most simple way to check the `m`-source `n`-terminal connectivity is to use `m+n-1`independent DFS runs (using the function above). However, this is not probably the most efficient way of doing the task, and would be slow if we want to do this task repetitively (say, for millions of graphs). What is the most efficient algorithm? What is the minimum number of the required DFS runs? I am using Python, and I prefer to use Networkx to perform connectivity check. Thanks!

Comment: Is the graph directed?

Comment: No, the graph is undirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way to do this for an undirected graph is to use networkx's [node_connected_component](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.node_connected_component.html?highlight=node_connected_component#networkx.algorithms.components.node_connected_component) command to find all the nodes in the same component as one of your source nodes.  Then check if all of the target and source nodes are also in that component.

The node_connected_component returns a list in 1.11 and a set in 2.0.  Probably the best way to do the test is to see if the set of sources and targets when intersected with the set of that component is equal to the set of sources and targets.